# How to compare two XML nodes and get compared result using XSLT?

Tags: xslt

XML file as input and expected output shown below. Can refere link...
[XSLT node value comparision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20739264/xslt-node-value-comparision/20820305?noredirect=1#comment31332691_20820305)

I am looking for output in xml but it would be great if anyone make xslt file which gives/shows result in tabular format.

Desc: XML file contains collection of operatorstation nodes, with each operator station has multiple networks, now collect IP address from each node of every operatorstation and show its value and compared status with every Operator station as shown below. If every operatorstation network IP is equal then it shows status as Equal otherwise Unequal. Comparison should be done with IPAddress with taking reference of Family and Name. Like compare IPAddress of OS01 with other OSs having same family (NetworkSettings) and Name (Network A).

XML file as input

```
![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OperatorStationCollection xmlns="http://www.w3.org" >
<OperatorStation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Name>KM-OS001</Name>
    <Nodes>
      <DataNodeBase xsi:type="Adaptor">
        <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
        <Name>Network A</Name>  
        <IPAddress>111.11.11.1</IPAddress>        
      </DataNodeBase>
      <DataNodeBase xsi:type="Adaptor">
        <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
        <Name>Network B</Name>                
        <IPAddress>111.22.11.1</IPAddress>          
      </DataNodeBase>
      <DataNodeBase xsi:type="Adaptor">
        <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
        <Name>Network C</Name>
        <IPAddress>111.33.11.1</IPAddress>
      </DataNodeBase>
      </Nodes>   
  </OperatorStation>      
<OperatorStation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Name>KM-OS002</Name>
  <Nodes>
    <DataNodeBase xsi:type="Adaptor">
      <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
      <Name>Network A</Name>
      <IPAddress>111.11.11.1</IPAddress>
    </DataNodeBase>
    <DataNodeBase xsi:type="Adaptor">
      <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
      <Name>Network B</Name>
      <IPAddress>111.22.11.2</IPAddress>
    </DataNodeBase>
    <DataNodeBase xsi:type="Adaptor">
      <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
      <Name>Network D</Name>
      <IPAddress>111.33.11.2</IPAddress>
    </DataNodeBase>
  </Nodes>
</OperatorStation>
  <OperatorStation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Name>KM-OS003</Name>
    <Nodes>
      <DataNodeBase xsi:type="Adaptor">
        <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
        <Name>Network A</Name>
        <IPAddress>111.11.11.1</IPAddress>
      </DataNodeBase>
      <DataNodeBase xsi:type="Adaptor">
        <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
        <Name>Network B</Name>
        <IPAddress>111.22.11.3</IPAddress>
      </DataNodeBase>
      <DataNodeBase xsi:type="Adaptor">
        <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
        <Name>Network E</Name>
        <IPAddress>111.33.11.3</IPAddress>
      </DataNodeBase>
    </Nodes>
  </OperatorStation>
</OperatorStationCollection>
```

Expected output.

Expected output using  XSLT:
Here no option to add table so please consider <> as separator which is used to design table, <> is not part of result it is just added to separate column values. Please consider below result as it is in table.

Header **Name<>Status<>OS01<>OS02<>OS03**

Network A<>Equal<>111.11.11.1<>111.11.11.1<>111.11.11.1

Network B<>Unequal<>111.22.11.1<>111.22.11.2<>111.22.11.2

Network C<>Unequal<>111.33.11.1<>Not Exist<>Not Exist

Network D<>Unequal<>Not Exist<>111.33.11.2<>Not Exist

Network E<>Unequal<>Not Exist<>Not Exist<>111.33.11.3

**OR Code below shows expected result in tabular format.**
Save below code fileName.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>    
</head>
<body>

   <table>
            <tr>
            <td>Name</td><td>Status</td><td>OS01</td><td>OS02</td><td>OS03</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Network A</td><td>Equal</td><td>111.11.11.1</td><td>111.11.11.1</td><td>111.11.11.1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Network B</td><td>Unequal</td><td>111.22.11.1</td><td>111.22.11.2</td><td>111.22.11.2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Network C</td><td>Unequal</td><td>111.33.11.1</td><td>Not Exist</td><td>Not Exist</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Network D</td><td>Unequal</td><td>Not Exist</td><td>111.33.11.2</td><td>Not Exist</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Network E</td><td>Unequal</td><td>Not Exist</td><td>Not Exist</td><td>111.33.11.3</td>
            </tr>           
            </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rather than drawing a representation of how you'd want the table rendered, it would be much more useful to show the actual XML/HTML source that you need to generate - we can't tell from this question whether you're looking for HTML, Docbook, XSL-FO, or something else entirely.

Comment: @lan, I have added html code, looking for quick response to get answer.Thanks

Comment: I am looking for output in xml format but it would be great if anyone make xslt file which gives/shows result in tabular format.Because xslt file itself has ability to transform xml data and shows result in tabular format.

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0 or are you limited to 1.0?

Comment: I am using 1.0 and its working for other results in my project, I don't know 2.0 will work or not !

Comment: If you aren't sure that you have 2.0 available then you almost certainly don't...

Comment: Please stop editing the question to remove all its content, as this invalidates the existing accepted answer.  Stack Overflow questions and answers are intended to be a searchable resource for anyone who might have a similar problem in future, so just because the question is no longer relevant _to you_ does not mean it will not be relevant to anyone else.  That said, if you have a good reason why the question should be deleted entirely (e.g. if it contains private data that should not have been there to start with) then you should flag it and let the moderators deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want one column per operator station name, and one row per *distinct* network name.  In XSLT 2.0 this can be done nicely using `for-each-group`

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:w3="http://www.w3.org" exclude-result-prefixes="w3">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="allStations"
                  select="/w3:OperatorStationCollection/w3:OperatorStation" />
    <table>
      <!-- Header row - two fixed columns plus one per station name -->
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td><td>Status</td>
        <xsl:for-each select="$allStations">
          <td><xsl:value-of select="w3:Name" /></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
      <!-- main rows - one per "group" of DataNodeBase elements which share the
           same Name -->
      <xsl:for-each-group
          select="$allStations/w3:Nodes/w3:DataNodeBase"
          group-by="w3:Name">
        <!-- calculate the column values - the IPAddress if this network (i.e. the
             current-group) has an entry for this station, and "None" if not -->
        <xsl:variable name="addresses"
            select="for $s in ($allStations)
                    return (current-group()[../.. is $s]/w3:IPAddress, 'None')[1]" />
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" /></td>
          <td>
            <!-- equal if all the $addresses are the same, unequal otherwise -->
            <xsl:value-of select="if (count(distinct-values($addresses)) = 1)
                                  then 'Equal' else 'Unequal'" />
          </td>
          <xsl:for-each select="$addresses">
            <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you're limited to 1.0 then the logic is the same but the stylesheet is much more verbose - you'll have to use the "Muenchian grouping" method to replace `for-each-group`, and the equal/unequal calculation is a bit messier because you don't have the `distinct-values` function or the capability to define arbitrary sequences of values (the `$addresses` variable in the 2.0 version):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
     xmlns:w3="http://www.w3.org" exclude-result-prefixes="w3">

  <!-- grouping key to pull out all the DataNodeBase elements with a
       particular name -->
  <xsl:key name="dnbByName" match="w3:DataNodeBase" use="w3:Name" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="allStations"
                  select="/w3:OperatorStationCollection/w3:OperatorStation" />
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td><td>Status</td>
        <xsl:for-each select="$allStations">
          <td><xsl:value-of select="w3:Name" /></td>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
      <!-- Muenchian grouping - for-each over a set consisting of just one
           DataNodeBase per network name "group" -->
      <xsl:for-each select="$allStations/w3:Nodes/w3:DataNodeBase[
            generate-id() = generate-id(key('dnbByName', w3:Name)[1])]">
        <xsl:variable name="current-group" select="key('dnbByName', w3:Name)" />
        <xsl:variable name="current-grouping-key" select="w3:Name" />
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="$current-grouping-key" /></td>
          <td>
            <xsl:choose>
              <!-- "Equal" if all stations have a value for this network name,
                   and all these values are the same (it is not the case that
                   any of the values is different from that of the first
                   station) -->
              <xsl:when test="count($current-group) = count($allStations)
                  and not($current-group/w3:IPAddress
                          != $current-group[1]/w3:IPAddress)">
                <xsl:text>Equal</xsl:text>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>Unequal</xsl:text>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </td>
          <!-- remaining columns, one per station -->
          <xsl:for-each select="$allStations">
            <td>
              <!-- check whether this station has an address for this network -->
              <xsl:variable name="address" select="w3:Nodes/w3:DataNodeBase[
                      w3:Name = $current-grouping-key]/w3:IPAddress" />
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$address">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$address" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>None</xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </td>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @lan, xslt scripting is new for me. I am not getting result, could you guide me even if I use XSLT 2.0 to get expected result. Now result comes blank. I am trying get result through  http://xslfiddle.net/

Comment: @AshishPayghan I don't think that site supports 2.0, try http://xsltransform.net instead.

Comment: @lan, I want xslt code for version 1.0 because I am working in .net and I tried with XSLT version 2.0, and it gives many errors like xsl:for-each-group is not yet implementaed.  Also need to add some extra third party exe like SAXON. Could you help me to get same result with version 1.0.

Comment: @lan, I tried with Muenchian grouping but I am still stuck and not got expected result, Hope to get help from you. I am referring this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560125/xslt-compare-two-different-nodes-and-then-combine

Comment: @AshishPayghan there are many (hundreds?) of examples of Muenchian grouping in other questions, but this particular case has enough other complications to make it not quite so straightforward.  I've added an example of how you could approach your problem in 1.0.