# How to get child nodes result instead of parent?

Tags: xslt

Below XSLT code gives me result by parent node compared result. I am looking for child node comparision result, expected result as shown below.
Desc: XSLT code gives parent node (Network A, Network B,etc) and I want child node(Network AA, Network AB, etc) compared result. I suggest you please check input xml file and expected output to understand my requirement easily. Please take reference of link [convert XSLT code from version 2.0 to 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917729/convert-xslt-code-from-version-2-0-to-1-0)

Input XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OperatorStationCollection >
  <OperatorStation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Name>OS001</Name>
    <Nodes>
      <DataNodeBase xsi:type="Adaptor">
        <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
        <Name>Network A</Name>
        <IPAddress>111.11.11.1</IPAddress>
        <ChildNodes>
            <DataNodeChild xsi:type="SubResult">
                <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
                <Name>Network AA</Name>
                <IPAddress>111.11.11.12</IPAddress>
            </DataNodeChild>
            <DataNodeChild xsi:type="SubResult">
                <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
                <Name>Network AB</Name>
                <IPAddress>111.11.11.13</IPAddress>
            </DataNodeChild>            
        </ChildNodes>
      </DataNodeBase>
      <DataNodeBase xsi:type="Adaptor">
        <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
        <Name>Network B</Name>
        <IPAddress>111.22.11.1</IPAddress>
        <ChildNodes>
            <DataNodeChild xsi:type="SubResult">
                <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
                <Name>Network BA</Name>
                <IPAddress>111.11.11.21</IPAddress>
            </DataNodeChild>
            <DataNodeChild xsi:type="SubResult">
                <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
                <Name>Network BB</Name>
                <IPAddress>111.11.11.31</IPAddress>
            </DataNodeChild>            
        </ChildNodes>
      </DataNodeBase>      
    </Nodes>
  </OperatorStation>
  <OperatorStation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Name>OS002</Name>
    <Nodes>
      <DataNodeBase xsi:type="Adaptor">
        <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
        <Name>Network A</Name>
        <IPAddress>111.11.11.1</IPAddress>
        <ChildNodes>
            <DataNodeChild xsi:type="SubResult">
                <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
                <Name>Network AA</Name>
                <IPAddress>111.11.11.12</IPAddress>
            </DataNodeChild>
            <DataNodeChild xsi:type="SubResult">
                <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
                <Name>Network AB</Name>
                <IPAddress>111.11.11.13</IPAddress>
            </DataNodeChild>            
        </ChildNodes>
      </DataNodeBase>
      <DataNodeBase xsi:type="Adaptor">
        <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
        <Name>Network B</Name>
        <IPAddress>111.22.11.1</IPAddress>
        <ChildNodes>
            <DataNodeChild xsi:type="SubResult">
                <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
                <Name>Network BA</Name>
                <IPAddress>111.11.11.12</IPAddress>
            </DataNodeChild>
            <DataNodeChild xsi:type="SubResult">
                <Family>NetworkSettings</Family>
                <Name>Network BB</Name>
                <IPAddress>111.11.11.13</IPAddress>
            </DataNodeChild>            
        </ChildNodes>
      </DataNodeBase>      
    </Nodes>
  </OperatorStation>
</OperatorStationCollection>
```

XSLT file

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:w3="http://www.w3.org">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="networks" match="w3:DataNodeBase" use="w3:Name"/>
   <xsl:key name="networksAndIP" match="w3:DataNodeBase" use="concat(w3:Name, '|', w3:IPAddress)"/>

   <xsl:variable name="allStations" select="//w3:OperatorStation"/>
   <xsl:variable name="allStationsCount" select="count($allStations)"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <table><!-- Header row - two fixed columns plus one per station name -->
         <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            <xsl:for-each select="$allStations">
               <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="w3:Name"/>
               </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </tr>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//w3:DataNodeBase[generate-id() = generate-id(key('networks', w3:Name)[1])]"/>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="w3:DataNodeBase">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="w3:Name"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="count(key('networksAndIP', concat(w3:Name, '|', w3:IPAddress))) = $allStationsCount">Equal</xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>Unequal</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
         </td>
         <xsl:variable name="network" select="w3:Name"/>
         <xsl:for-each select="$allStations">
            <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="key('networks', $network)[../../w3:Name=current()/w3:Name]/w3:IPAddress"/>
            </td>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected OUTPUT: As there is no provision to add table , I have made hatml code for result, please save this code to html file and see expected output. For understanding I have made I have made table, I am looking for output in xml but it would be great if anyone make xslt file which gives/shows result in tabular format.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>    
</head>
<body>

   <table>
            <tr>
            <td>Name</td><td>Status</td><td>OS01</td><td>OS02</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Network AB</td><td>Equal</td><td>111.11.11.12</td><td>111.11.11.12</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Network AB</td><td>Equal</td><td>111.11.11.13</td><td>111.11.11.13</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Network BA</td><td>Unequal</td><td>111.11.11.21</td><td>111.11.11.12</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Network BB</td><td>Unequal</td><td>111.11.11.31</td><td>111.11.11.13</td>
            </tr>                   
            </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IMHO, after having a very similar question answered three times already, you should be able to figure this out by yourself.

Comment: XSLT is very new for me and I don't have time to learn it due to lack of time.I never raised any question without trial, and even you can see questions are similar but not easy.Your help is appreciated otherwise I have to complete it anyhow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare two XML nodes and get compared result using XSLT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901103/how-to-compare-two-xml-nodes-and-get-compared-result-using-xslt)

Comment: To learn new skills is a wonderful thing. I think you need to make time to learn, and you will be rewarded with your new knowledge!

Comment: Possible solutions: **1.** Do not take on tasks that require knowledge of XSLT;   **2.** Take the time necessary to learn it;   **3.** Hire someone that already did.   **Not listed:** asking people to spend *their* time writing code for you for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before answering, I am assuming you have missed out a namespace declaration in your XML, and that the root element should actually look like this (If not, you will need to remove all trace of the namespace from XSLT too)

```
<OperatorStationCollection xmlns="http://www.w3.org">
```

In your previous question you were grouping by **DataNodeBase**, but in your new question, you are grouping by **DataNodeChild**. This means all you really need to do is literally replace all occurences of **DataNodeBase** by **DataNodeChild** in your XSLT.

The only other change to make is to this line

```
<xsl:value-of 
     select="key('networks', $network)[../../w3:Name=current()/w3:Name]/w3:IPAddress"/>
```

Because **DataNodeChild** is nested two further levels done, the expression has to be changed accordingly

```
<xsl:value-of 
     select="key('networks', $network)[../../../../w3:Name=current()/w3:Name]/w3:IPAddress"/>
```

Better still, to cope with it at any level, it could be this

```
<xsl:value-of 
     select="key('networks', $network)[ancestor::w3:OperatorStation/w3:Name=current()/w3:Name]/w3:IPAddress"/>
```

And that's it. Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:w3="http://www.w3.org">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="networks" match="w3:DataNodeChild" use="w3:Name"/>
   <xsl:key name="networksAndIP" match="w3:DataNodeChild" use="concat(w3:Name, '|', w3:IPAddress)"/>
   <xsl:variable name="allStations" select="//w3:OperatorStation"/>
   <xsl:variable name="allStationsCount" select="count($allStations)"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <table><!-- Header row - two fixed columns plus one per station name -->
         <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            <xsl:for-each select="$allStations">
               <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="w3:Name"/>
               </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </tr>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//w3:DataNodeChild[generate-id() = generate-id(key('networks', w3:Name)[1])]"/>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="w3:DataNodeChild">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="w3:Name"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="count(key('networksAndIP', concat(w3:Name, '|', w3:IPAddress))) = $allStationsCount">Equal</xsl:when>
               <xsl:otherwise>Unequal</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
         </td>
         <xsl:variable name="network" select="w3:Name"/>
         <xsl:for-each select="$allStations">
            <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="key('networks', $network)[ancestor::w3:OperatorStation/w3:Name=current()/w3:Name]/w3:IPAddress"/>
            </td>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```